# Specifying view for PS Script to Pull Sharepoint Enterprise List Data

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, view, listitem

I am trying to create a PowerShell script to pull a bunch of data for report files from our enterprise Sharepoint Site.
Using getlistitems I am able to pull a decent chunk of the required data from our lists, but it appears to only be returning items from the default view of each list. I'd like to set it to pull from 'All Items' view, but am struggling to get it. See my code below.

```
$serverurl = "https:linkhiddenforprivacy/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx"
$xml = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $serverurl -UseDefaultCredential
$dslist = $xml.GetListCollection()
$overalllist = $dslist.ChildNodes
foreach($listitem in $overalllist) {
    try {

        $xmlDoc = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
        $query = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query")
        $viewFields = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("ViewFields")
        $queryOptions = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("QueryOptions")
        $queryOptions.InnerXml = "<ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll' IncludeMandatoryColumns='FALSE' />"
        $rowLimit = "10000"
        $view = $overalllist.views["All Items"]

        $listitems = $xml.getlistitems($listitem.id, $view ,$null, $null, $rowLimit, $queryOptions, $null).data.row 
        foreach($child in $listitems) {
            if($child.ows_DocIcon -eq "rdl"){
                $vs = $xml.GetVersionCollection($listitem.ID, $child.ows_ID, "_UIVersionString")
                $childlib = $child.ows_FileRef
                $childname = $child.ows_LinkFileName 
                [string]$childowner = $child.ows_ReportOwner
                $childcategory = $child.ows_ReportCategory
                $childdescription = $child.ows_ReportDescription
                $childstatus = $child.ows_ReportStatus
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                        'Doctype' = $child.ows_DocIcon
                        'Library' = $childlib.substring($childlib.indexof('#') + 1, $childlib.lastindexof('/') - $childlib.indexof('#') - 1)
                        'Report' = $childname
                        'Owner' = $childOwner.Substring($childowner.indexof('#') + 1, $childowner.Length - $childowner.IndexOf('#') - 1)
                        'Category' = $childCategory
                        'Description' = $childDescription
                        'Status' = $childStatus
                        'Version' = $vs.Version[0]._UIVersionString
                        'Childlib' = $childlib
                } | Export-Csv output.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
            }
```

I have tried a few variations of this and am not having any success. I am new to Powershell, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSOM in PowerShell, you could get items based on a view easily.

Sample script:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"  
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"  

$siteURL = "http://sp:12001"   
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteURL)  

try{  
    $lists = $ctx.web.Lists  
    $list = $lists.GetByTitle("MyList")  
    $view = $list.Views.GetByTitle("All Items")
    $ctx.load($view)        
    $ctx.executeQuery()
    $query=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
    $query.ViewXml = $view.ViewQuery;
    $listItems = $list.GetItems($query)  
    $ctx.load($listItems)        
    $ctx.executeQuery()  
    foreach($listItem in $listItems)  
    {  
        Write-Host "ID - " $listItem["ID"] "Title - " $listItem["Title"]  
    }  
}  
catch{  
    write-host "$($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor red  
}
```

Get CSOM SDK from [2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585) [2016](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51679) or [online](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038)

You could get lots of demo if you try to search CSOM with PowerShell in SharePoint.

Comment: Thankyou, unfortunately I am unable to install additional software due to group policy/security concerns. I can only use the method that follows my code provided in my example.

Comment: You could install the CSOM SDK in your local and just copy the dlls to target server and use it.

Comment: You could check https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/export-list-items-using-sharepoint-2010-web-service-in-power/ if you want to try lists.asmx, it's more popular to use CSOM or pnp powershell now.